# How to prevent UINavigationBar from covering top of view in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

After updating to Xcode 5, the navigation bars in all of my app's views have shifted down. Here are some screenshots, the first showing everything in the view as it's pulled down, and the second showing all of it untouched. The search bar should begin where the navigation bar.

[image: All Content]
[image: All Content on Idle]

Anyone know how I can fix this?

edit: i have tried this previously recommendation:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

But it yields very odd results.

[image: Solution Attempt]

This may be because I have a "slide menu" under this view controller that is appearing due to the transparency of the navigation bar.

Comment: Here you are another solution for this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491645/10148333

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Set the **navigation bar's translucent property to NO**:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

This will fix the view from being framed underneath the navigation bar and status bar.

If you have to show and hide the navigation bar, then use

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;   // iOS 7 specific
```

in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I have placed this under `viewDidLoad` however it yields no changes.

Comment: make it in viewDidLayoutSubviews funtions

Comment: Appending this to viewDidLayoutSubviews did the trick. I appreciate the help gentlemen!

Comment: Hi, Any Question? or is it compliment?

Comment: @kokx I have implemented whatever you and said but I am still having same problem

Comment: try in -(void) viewWillLayoutSubviews method

Comment: For detailed insight read [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide. Chapter: Appearance and Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html).


  [1]:

Comment: Worked like a charm for me in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. THANK you Deepesh. Upvote.

Comment: In xcode5, you can set the Navigation Bar to be not Translucent under the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; helped me

Answer (score 34):

In `iOS 7` by defaults **all Controller translucent property value is YES, so you set translucent property NO** for this issue.

```
self.navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: There is no "navController" property. Use this: self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Comment: i create navigtionbarcontroller object in app delegate and give name navController.

Answer (score 21):

You can disable 
the "Extend edges" in Attribute inspector of View Controller of this screen (as shown in below image)
:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

This works for swift as well on iOS 8.1

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep the translucency on your `navigationBar`, at the end of your `viewDidLoad` or in your `viewWillAppear` add this line of code:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.tableView]
```

Somehow if your `scrollView` subclass (`UITableView`, `UICollectionView`, etc.) is at `index` 0 in your current view `subviews`, it will automatically adjust the insets according to your `navigationBar`. And it shouldn't affect your UI in versions prior to iOS7 either.

**EDIT**
If you initialize your `UITableView` programmatically, then it is best to add it to the view using this `[self.view insertSubview:self.tableView atIndex:0];`

Comment: This should be the correct answer. If you are adding the subview programmatically you can just do `[self.view insertSubview:self.tableView atIndex:0];` instead of sending it to the back after you add it.

Comment: Correct. But without knowing how he's initiating his controller (programmatically, interface builder), we can't assume that it is the best solution. Although I've edited my answer.

Comment: This works but looks like a hack. Is there any notice in official documentation about this?

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**:

Set following line of code in viewDidLoad method:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add this method into your view controller as shown on this [URL](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2013/09/developing-for-ios-7-and-supporting-ios-6/):

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.searchBar.frame = 
    CGRectMake(0, self.topOfViewOffset, self.searchBar.frame.size.width, self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;` on your view controller.
This is enabled by default. But in your case:

I see you are using EGORefreshHeaderView. It plays with contentInset of UITableView. So when you release it, header will reset top inset instead of restore previous value.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have complete control on views and avoid faulty adjustments of iOS, subclass UITableView and adjust the insets (both scroll and indicators) in `-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow`. Works for me.

Answer (score -4):

Another option is to open your Info.plist file in source code mode and enter the following info:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think this would affect the view at all.