# Difference in layout of simulator and XIB

Tags: iphone, ios, xib

I have an issue in position of UI on window through XIB
I have added some images in XIB below navigation bar but when i run the app then in simulator its showing first two image under navigation bar i.e upper images and overlapped by navigation controller. 
Use autolayout is disabled for view.
Position of first two images view is show X=0 y = 0 and x = 160 and y =0.

I think this is case in IOS 7 only

Please see the screenshots at

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=so9z5t&s=5

One more problem in below mentioned screenshot

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=a11tug&s=5

Image view is staring from y=0 but when running then on simulator its showing too much below. and black area is view

image view is sliding lower down.. very very mush odd behaviour of Xcode 5

Comment: Refer this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953509/how-to-prevent-navigation-bar-from-covering-top-of-view-in-ios-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `iOS 7` by defaults all Controller translucent property value is `YES`, so you set translucent property `NO` for this issue.

> self.navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;