# How to set UINavigationBar in iOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar

I made app in iOS6. As I run on iOS7, it shows are

[image: Navigation Bar issue]

I tried this code, but no use.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];

nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

What should I do. My xib is like this

[image: Inspector]

Comment: Whosoever down vote, must tell reason.

Comment: see my so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953509/how-to-prevent-navigation-bar-from-covering-top-of-view-in-ios-7/18953585#18953585

Comment: refer this link it helpfull to you [Customizing Navigation Bar and Status Bar in iOS 7](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/)

Comment: Thanks. Awesome solution :)

Answer (score 0):

add these lines of code in your viewDidLoad

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
{
    // iOS 7
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
}
else
{
    // iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

and define this method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

This working for me.. Best of luck .. :-)

Comment: Its not working dear.

Comment: wait a min .. let me check on device. Because it perfectly working in simulator

Comment: I am also working on simulator dear.

Answer (score 0):

Add this two line in your `viewDidLoad` method

```
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)])
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

Hope this will help you.