# How to prevent top bar from impeding view

Tags: ios, ipad, layout

I'm writing my first iOS app and have noticed that the top bar appears over my application:

[image]

My main window is created like this:

```
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

I noticed [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953509/how-to-prevent-navigation-bar-from-covering-top-of-view-in-ios-7), but I do not have a navigation controller. My root controller is a tab controller.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `applicationFrame` instead of `bounds`. `bounds` will return you size including status bar while `applicationFrame` will return you frame of content for your app.

```
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

In iOS7 status bar can be translucent. This means that `applicationFrame` and `bounds` will return same frame because content can be drawn bellow status bar. To fix this you can offset you window bellow status bar (`20px`)

```
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
_window.clipsToBounds = YES;
_window.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 20, _window.frame.size.width, _window.frame.size.height - 20);
_window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, _window.frame.size.width, _window.frame.size.height);
```

To make this work on all versions, add system version condition, like this:

```
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    _window.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _window.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 20, _window.frame.size.width, _window.frame.size.height - 20);
    _window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, _window.frame.size.width, _window.frame.size.height);
}
```

It's still better to avoid modifying window frame, use `applicationFrame` and offset your content view for `20px` from the top on iOS7 with translucent status bar.