# Static/fixed Navigation Bar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Navigation Controller and a Collection View under it inside my app. And there is a problem: I use large title inside my Navigation bar, so everything inside is not static. When I scroll the collection view cells, the title (I created it manually using `UILabel()` to move it as I want inside the navigation bar) and buttons move up and the navigation bar takes form of iOS 10 navigation bar, I mean its height. You can see it here:

The normal state of my Navigation Bar with "Prefer large titles" On:

[image]

It happens when I scroll my Collection View, everything goes up:

[image]

So the question is simple: how to make the force constant height for the navigation bar? I want it to become fixed even while scrolling. Are there any ideas? Is it possible?

And the second question, if the first is impossible: Another solution for my problem is to make the Navigation Bar with "Prefer large titles" Off bigger. I tried this code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let height: CGFloat = 50 //whatever height you want to add to the existing height
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
}
```

but it worked only for large titles. So how can I make the navigation bar bigger?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can make it fixed. It will not scroll if the very first view in the view hierarchy is not a `CollectionView/TableView (ScrollView)`.

**Using Storyboard/Xib:**

Consider the following image where a `tableView` and `button` are added in `scene`. Here the `navigation bar` will collapse on scroll of `tableView` because `tableView` is the very first view in `viewController`'s `containerView` hierarchy attached to the navigation bar.

[image]

Now to make the navigation bar fixed, if we just change the order of `tableView` and `button` as below, it will disable the collapsing of `navigation bar`.

[image]

To change the order of the `view`, you have to click, hold and move up/down.

If you have only `CollectionView` in this scene then you can add a placeholder `view` at the top and set its `height` to `zero` as below,

[image]

**Programmatically:**

If you are setting up view's programmatically then you just need to add a placeholder view at the top or add `tableView/collection` after adding other views.

e.g,

```
self.view.addSubview(UIView(frame: .zero))
self.view.addSubview(tableView) // or collectionView
```

Comment: Could you please suggest me, how can I change its size?

Comment: @MrBlazOn As of now, its not recommended to change the height. You can still find here some options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387285/ios-11-navigation-bar-height-customizing