# Stop Large Title Navigation Bar From Collapsing

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

How do I stop a large title navigation bar from collapsing when a `UIScrollView` is scrolled? I have tried setting

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

but that did not work. Another question had an answer suggesting just to add

```
view.addSubview(UIView())
```

to the `viewDidLoad()` but this did not work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static/fixed Navigation Bar in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486867/static-fixed-navigation-bar-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

this answer by Kamran has a great explanation of how to do this.

[Fixed Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486867/static-fixed-navigation-bar-in-ios)

Good luck!`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486867/static-fixed-navigation-bar-in-ios`